# How to switch off numeric keypad in BT keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, keyboard-layout

I've recently bought a compact Bluetooth keyboard. In Ubuntu, it works fine when wired, but when connecting it with Bluetooth, only some keys work, those around the <kbd>U</kbd>, and they correspond to a numeric keypad. I can fix this by switching off the <kbd>BloqNum</kbd> key with other keyboard, but the problem persists when I'm logging in, so in practice this doesn't solve my problem, since I would like to use just the BT keyboard.

Is there a way to change this behaviour in Ubuntu? I've seen some solutions involving access to *System → Preferences → Keyboard → Layout → Layout Options → Miscellaneous compatibility options*, but I can't find those options in my Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Thanks for the editing Elia, much better now

Comment: Those options are in `Gnome-Tweaks` `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`

Comment: Thanks, I have already searched there, and coudn't find the *Miscellaneous compatibility options* section. I have searched again, and now I found it, but it didn't solve my problem, I'm still unable to use my BT keyboard at the logging screen.

Comment: after logging in, is the BT keyboard working as expected? https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjHPd.png

Comment: Yes, it is. Anyway, there there is another problem with function keys not working, but to be honest, Linux was not officially supported for this keyboard (Keychron K2) so nothing to complain here. I think I will sell my two keyboards to people using Windows or Mac, since it work swiftly with these O.S.

Answer (score 7):

This should fix your issue, it did for me with Keychron K4.

`echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/module/hid_apple/parameters/fnmode`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue (with the same keyboard), and managed to solve this using the numlockx package. Simply:

```
sudo apt install numlockx                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
numlockx off
```

---

Comment: thanks, but the problem persists while logging into the system, so I'm still unable to use the keyboard until logged. And yet I can't use function keys. I think I'm gonna sell my two keyboards to mac/windows users.

Comment: This is the correct answer and solution.